# My Select does not appear

Tags: php, materialize

I'm on a product editing page, so i have first option to show the old record, and the second to show the rest of the options. Yes I have a query to show the first option. I'm using materialize.

```
<i class="material-icons prefix">payment</i>
<select name="NomeMarca">
<option value="<?php echo $row['idBrand']?>" disabled selected><?php echo $row['name'] ?></option>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * From brands Order by idBrand";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['idBrand'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</select>
<label>Marca</label>
```

html

```
<i class="material-icons prefix">payment</i>
<select name="NomeMarca">
<option value="2" disabled selected>Konica-Minolta</option>
    <option value="2">Konica-Minolta</option>
    <option value="3">Kyocera</option>
    <option value="4">Xerox</option>
    <option value="5">Samsung</option>
    <option value="6">Brother</option>
    <option value="7">Lexmark</option>
    <option value="8">Canon</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Does it show the old record?  If so, please add the php that got the old record.

Comment: I'm on the page and the select does not appear, but the label appears

Comment: Gerard H. Pille dont show the select so dont show anything.

Comment: have you checked the error log to see if there are any problems?

Comment: @PhilippMaurer what DOM sry for my innocence.

Comment: you haven't got some css set to hide that select element by any chance? ie: `display:none;` etc??

Comment: @RamRaider i dont have css in select.

Comment: @PhilippMaurer yes its in HTML

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that you can shorten all those `echo`s by using the shorthand tag syntax: `<?= $row['foo']; ?>`

Comment: @philippMaurer my html it's to big are you sure?

Comment: @PhilippMaurer it's there my select, but the option go search in my DB

Comment: @philippMaurer it's this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the correct links are declared on the top of the document!

Answer (score 0):

Try this for debugging, it personally helped me when I add this kind of problem:
    select class="browser-default"

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by either adding `class="browser-default"` or initializing it with js as explained in documentation.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
  });
```